# How to get a font file icon?

Tags: delphi, winapi, icons

I can get font folder icon like this :

```
var
sfi : SHFILEINFO;
begin
  SHGetFileInfo('C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial' , 0 , sfi , SizeOf(sfi) , SHGFI_ICON);
  Image1.Picture.Icon.Handle := sfi.hIcon;
end;
```

but fail like this :

```
var
sfi : SHFILEINFO;
begin
  SHGetFileInfo('C:\Windows\Fonts\ARIALN.TTF' , 0 , sfi , SizeOf(sfi) , SHGFI_ICON);  
  Image1.Picture.Icon.Handle := sfi.hIcon;
end;
```

it seem like can't get font file's icon but can get font folder , I wonder how to get a font file icon ?

Comment: What's to stop you using the code that works? Also, why aren't you doing error checking?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan could you tell how to do error checking?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the API call.

Comment: @ONion: I don't get what you are looking for. Apparently the first version does give you the 'icon of a TTF file'. You can also find this in shell32.dll, I guess. I suspect that, in fact, you are *not* looking for this icon, but rather for the font thumbnail generated by Explorer. This is not called an 'icon'. (Compare with the case of a BMP image. You don't want the generic BMP file icon, but rather the thumbnail of the actual BMP image data.) OR, perhaps, are you looking for icon 75 (say) in shell32.dll?

Comment: It would appear you cannot get a font file icon from the shell for an installed font because there's not one, the shell does not display individual font files for installed fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Windows Shell to get font file icon :

**Code :**

```
var
  psfDeskTop : IShellFolder;
  psfFont : IShellFolder;
  pEnumList : IEnumIdList;
  pidFont : PItemIdList;
  pidChild : PItemIdList;
  FontPath : array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of Char;
  IconFile : array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of Char;
  pchEaten, dwAttributes, ItemsFetched : ULONG;
  ExtractIcon : IExtractIcon;
  IconIndex : Integer;
  Flags : DWORD;
  Icon : TIcon;
  LH, SH : HICon;
begin
  FillChar(FontPath, sizeof(FontPath), #0);
  //get C:\Windows\Fonts
  SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, FontPath, CSIDL_FONTS, False);
  SHGetDesktopFolder(psfDeskTop);
  psfDeskTop.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, FontPath, pchEaten, pidFont,
    dwAttributes);
  //get font folder's interface
  psfDeskTop.BindToObject(pidFont, nil, IID_IShellFolder, psfFont);
  //Enumerate
  psfFont.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_FOLDERS or SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or
    SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN, pEnumList);
  ItemsFetched := 0;

  while pEnumList.Next(1, pidChild, ItemsFetched) = NO_ERROR do
  begin

    psfFont.GetUIObjectOf(0, 1, pidChild, IID_IExtractIconW, nil,
      Pointer(ExtractIcon));

    Flags := 0;
    LH := 0;
    SH := 0;

    if Assigned(ExtractIcon) then
    begin
      IconIndex := 0;
      Icon := TIcon.Create;
      ExtractIcon.GetIconLocation(0, @IconFile, MAX_PATH, IconIndex,
        Flags);
      if (IconIndex < 0) or ((Flags and GIL_NOTFILENAME) = 0) then
        ExtractIconEx(@IconFile, IconIndex, LH, SH, 1)
      else
        ExtractIcon.Extract(@IconFile, IconIndex, LH, SH, MakeLong(32,
          16));

      //get font file icon's handle LS for large icon , SH for small icon
      //do something u want 

    end;

  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want the icon *associated with the file type* of a font file (TTF, for instance). Then you can just ask for this. For instance,

```
var
  sfi: SHFILEINFO;
begin
  SHGetFileInfo('C:\SomeFileThatNeedNotEvenExist.ttf',
    0, sfi, SizeOf(sfi), SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES or SHGFI_ICON);
  Image1.Picture.Icon.Handle := sfi.hIcon;
```

will get you the icon associated with TTF files.

Comment: What's the difference between OP's version and yours? `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES`?

Comment: Yes. With that flag the file need not even exists. So it is ideally suited to get the icon associated with a particular file *type* (*extension*), which I suspect is what the OP really wants.

Comment: On the other hand, if the file does exist, it is better to pass the real filename, in case the file has a custom icon assigned to it that is different than the generic icon that is associated with the file extension.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well, but that is normally not the case, and in particular, it is not the case for fonts, is it? Also, given the difficulties invovled in working with the Fonts 'directory', this approach feels a lot safer.

Comment: +1, in fact a quick test shows SHGetFileInfo does not even succeed when an existing font file in the fonts folder is passed without the SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES flag, probably because the shell does not display the font files at all. There's also no point in passing an existing file (for a font file) for the same reason.